# Connect postgresql with databricks

Tags: databricks

Hi can anyone please let me know the steps required to connect with postgresql from databricks.
It will be helpful for me.
I am trying to connect postgresql with databricks using below query
`[Link I am referring](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/external-systems/postgresql.html)`

I am using jdbc to connect with postgres.

Every time I am getting error like connection attempt failed.

If possible please share the image also of testing.

Comment: please add exception or stacktrace?